# Right exact sequence of tensor algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be a ring. Given an exact sequence of $R$-modules $$K\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow0$$ deduce $$T(N)\otimes K\otimes T(N)\longrightarrow T(N)\longrightarrow T(M)\longrightarrow0$$ is exact.

Here we define for any $R$-module $M$, $T(M):=R\oplus M\oplus (M\otimes_RM)\oplus(M\otimes_RM\otimes_RM)\oplus\dots$

Is it possible to use right exactness of tensor product to prove this ?

Comment: Are you sure that T(N) occurs twice in the last term?

Comment: @user26857 Yes, $T(N)$ occurs twice in the term involving $K$.But for $S(N)=T(N)/(a\otimes b-b\otimes a)$ and all $T()$ replaced by $S()$, the first term would be $K\otimes S(N)$

Comment: Also, if needed, we may define the product of $x_1\otimes x_2\otimes\dots\otimes x_i$ and $y_1\otimes y_2\otimes\dots\otimes y_j$ in $T(M)$ as $x_1\otimes x_2\otimes\dots\otimes x_i\otimes y_1\otimes y_2\otimes\dots\otimes y_j$ to make $T(M)$ into $R$-algebra

Comment: So to be clear, this amounts to proving that if some $x\in N^{\otimes n}$ is zero in $(N/K)^{\otimes n}$, then it can be written as a sum of pure tensors $a_1\otimes\cdots\otimes a_n$ with at least one $a_i$ in $K$.